# Why don't they put a link to the homepage of the answerer in the the answer

Tags: feature-request, homepage, incentive

Right if I answer or ask a question it puts a link to my profile, but if it also had link to homepage right there it would be much better. It will be an incentive to answer questions also.

**EDIT** : It doesn't have to be another link, just the same link can be made to go to the homepage.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not so sure, I think it'd just make the questions look more spammy and clutter things up. If people want to go to someone's homepage then they can easily find it by clicking on their profile, but most of the time people just want to answer a question rather than be slapped in the face with someone's website as well!

Comment: I disagree! We should be loading the user's entire site in an iframe for everyone to see! [ducks]

Comment: @Tim Post surely popups would be better? Popups of every site of everyone that's commented on the page?

Comment: And what about some killer tunes? I vote for "[greensleeves](http://www.madore.org/~david/music/midi/greensle.mid)".

Comment: <bgsound> tag ftw!

Comment: I think the OP wanted the profile link to go to his website or something. What is wrong with it? Users decide whether to click or not. Silly comments.